# php remove redundant words from string range

Tags: php, string

I have a range of information. For example:

Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO Volume 1 Chapter 5 Page 10

what is the fastest way to remove redundant information and convert this to:

Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO Chapter 5 Page 10

OR if the input is

Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 10
then output

Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO Page 10

Comment: `remove redundant information` -- why not convert it to `Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO 10`?

Comment: And what if data will be `Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO Volume 1 Chapter 5 Page 10` ? What should be the result?

Comment: Yes, why do you consider "Page" in "TO Page" not redundant? What is the criteria for redundancy?

Comment: Beside the numbers, the wording is going to change? I think we need a more complex solution here, I suggest getting the numeric values and doing a math calculation to get the right final wording

Comment: @devnull right. should have been TO chapter 5

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo then should be TO Chapter 5 Page 10 (i.e. remove volume 1)

Answer (score 2):

The hardest part here is to split the input into tokens, as it's not structured well enough. I used a recursive function to sequentially clean the string of the first element duplicates. It works correctly for this input, but I am not sure, that it's 100% correct, as input structure is unclear:

```
<?php
$str = 'Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 10';
$str = clear_first_element_duplicates($str);
var_dump($str);

function clear_first_element_duplicates($str)
{
    if (preg_match('/(.*?\d)\s(.*)/', $str, $tokens))
    {
        $regexp = preg_quote($tokens[1]);
        $str = preg_replace("/$regexp\s?/", '', $tokens[2]);
        return $tokens[1]." ".clear_first_element_duplicates($str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Prints:

```
"Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO Page 10"
```

Comment: $str = 'Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO Volume 2 Chapter 3 Page 10'; will ignore the chapter on the volume 2, it will output "volume 2 page 10"

Answer (score 0):

My script seems complex but worth it:

I Added variable Levels, So it's not restricted to just Volume, chapter and pages, you can add for example paragraph line and character if desired, and you can even change the Wording. See examples at the end.

** BE careful with the $separator parameter, it must be Exact(case sensitive) and might appear only once on the script, this is easy to fix but I focused on the important part of the function **

```
function redundancy($string, $separator){
    list($a, $b) = explode($separator, $string);

    //getting the numeric values of both sides
    $pattern = '/[0-9]+/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $a, $a_values);
    preg_match_all($pattern, $b, $b_values);

    $a_values = $a_values[0];
    $b_values = $b_values[0];

    //getting the wording and cleaning out the numbers, I guess this can be improved through a better REGEX
    preg_match_all('/\b\w+\b/', $a, $matches);
    foreach($matches[0] as $match){
        if(!is_numeric($match)) $words[] = $match;
    }

    //algorithm
    $length = count($a_values) - 1; // excluding the last element, to be checked separately
    $output = $a.$separator." ";
    $same_full_path = true; // check if the levels has been altered to check the last element
    $same_parent = true; // check the previous level
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        if($a_values[$i] !== $b_values[$i] || $same_parent === false){
            $same_parent = false;
            $same_full_path = false;
            $output .= $words[$i]." ".$b_values[$i]." ";
        }
    }

    //adding the word to the last element or not, The last element check must be outside the loop because it's special;
    if($same_full_path === false || end($a_values) === end($b_values)) $output .= end($words)." ";
    $output .= end($b_values);

    echo "$string <Br/> $output; <br/><br/> ";
}

redundancy('Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO Volume 1 Chapter 5 Page 10', 'TO');
redundancy('Serie 1 Season 2 Chapter 2 Minute 5 Second 6 Until Serie 1 Season 3 Chapter 4 Minute 3 Second 1', 'Until');
redundancy('District 4 Building 2 Floor 4 Door 5 To District 4 Building 2 Floor 4 Door 8', 'To');
```

---

Outputs :

Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO Volume 1 Chapter 5 Page 10

Volume 1 Chapter 3 Page 5 TO Chapter 5 Page 10;

-

Serie 1 Season 2 Chapter 2 Minute 5 Second 6 Until Serie 1 Season 3 Chapter 4 Minute 3 Second 1

Serie 1 Season 2 Chapter 2 Minute 5 Second 6 Until Season 3 Chapter 4 Minute 3 Second 1;

-

District 4 Building 2 Floor 4 Door 5 To District 4 Building 2 Floor 4 Door 8

District 4 Building 2 Floor 4 Door 5 To 8;